# how can i find the average of this?

Tags: java, arrays, math, average

I'm new to java programming and i just cant figure out how to find the average of an array nor do i know how to print the array backwards. This is my code so far:

```
public static void forwards(int nums, int arrayNums[]){
    for(int a=0;a<arrayNums.length;a++){
        nums =(int)(Math.random()*90+10);
        System.out.print(nums+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    //Average of the array
    int average=0;
    for(int b=0;b<arrayNums.length; b++){
        average=(average+arrayNums[b]);

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(average);
}

public static void backwards(int nums, int[] arrayNums){
    //backwards of the array
    for(int a=arrayNums.length; a>0;a--){
        System.out.print(nums+" ");
    }
}


public static void main (String [] args){
    int[] arrayNums = new int [Integer.parseInt
            (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers do you want to input?"))];
    int nums = 1;
    forwards(nums,arrayNums);
    System.out.println();
    backwards(nums,arrayNums);
```

Comment: Too much is wrong to list it all. Start with the `backwards()` and `forwards()` routines. What do you think parameter `nums` is? What do you think you are doing with it?

Answer (score 0):

For average `---->`

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 sum += array[i];
}

int avegare =  sum / array.length;
```

For Backwards `---->`

```
for(int i = Array.length - 1; i >= 0;i--)
```

Comment: Care to give an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Backwards should start with `arrayNums.length-1`:

```
public static void backwards(int nums, int[] arrayNums){
    //backwards of the array
    for(int a=arrayNums.length-1; a >= 0; a--){
        System.out.print(arrayNums[a]+" ");
    }
}
```

The reason is that indices go from `0` to `array.length-1`. That's basically what happens in a for loop.

For the average, you forgot a division by the number of elements...

Comment: Care to give more of an explanation? Also you say to start with `arrayNums.length - 1` but your code example does not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to find the average. Just add up each of the elements, and then divide by the total number of elements in the array:

```
public static double average(int[] array)
{
    int average =0; 
    for(int i =0; i< array.length; i++ )
    {
      average += array[i]; 
    }
    return average/array.length;
}
```

Here is a backwards method. Start at `array.length-1`, which is the last index. From there, iterate down `i--`, and then end when `i` is zero.

```
public static void printBackwards(int[] array)
{
   for(int i  =array.length-1; i>= 0; i--)
  {
    System.out.print(array[i] +" ");
  }
}
```

When you call the methods, this is the syntax you should use:

```
double avg = average(arrayNums);
System.out.println(avg);

printBackwards(arrayNums);
```

Comment: Care to give an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> "i just cant figure out how to find the average of an array nor do i know how to print the array backwards."

1. For averages, you should use a different method, instead of trying to it in the `forwards` method

   ```
   public static double average(int[] arrayNums) {
       double sum = 0;
       ... 
       double average = // how do you get the average of something?
       return average;
   }
   ```

   I started you off with the basic outline. You basically need to add all the numbers to the sum, by looping through the array, then get the average by diving it by the total of numbers in the array. Then you can print out the average like

   ```
   double average = average(array);
   System.out.println(average)
   ```
2. for backwards, you want to print `arrayNums[a]` instead of `nums`. You should also start the loop from `arrayNum.length - 1` as there is no index in the array `arrayNums.length` so you would get an `ArerayOutOfBounds` exception. Also you want the 0th index, so you want to use `>=`

   ```
    for(int a = arrayNums.length - 1; a >= 0  ;a--) {
         // print arrayNums[a]
   ```
3. You seem to be doing the same wrong thing for `forwards` as you are in `backwards`. You want to print the arrays value for each index `a`, and not `nums`
4. I would also create the `random` array in a different method

   ```
    public static int[] randomArray(int num) {
        int[] random = new int[nums];

             .... may array by looping
        return random;
    }
   ```

   Then you the `main` you could just do

   ```
    int[] array = randomArray(num);
    forwards(array);
    backwards(array);
    double average = average(array);
    System.out.println(average);
   ```
5. As you can see, I pass no `nums` to the methods. I think you should take tha parameter out of the method signatures. I see no use for them.

Comment: Starting at 0 would not be a backwards loop. I think the OP had the direction right. ; )

Comment: @Radiodef thanks, I was getting frustrated looking at all the mistakes, so I rushed through this. +1 to you.

Comment: NP though your loop still starts at `length`. Also I know how it is. Originally I was writing my own answer but then I saw the comment by @John3136 which indicated there were mistakes I hadn't seen. The "code only" answers had started to come in at that point so I gave up.